# How do I create a data table and pass in information?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I want to insert more than 1000 rows of data into a SQL table so I need to use SqlBulkCopy. However it appears I need to create a DataTable first. Therefore, how do you add data to the DataTable? I want to add dynamically generated data from a dictionary into the DataTable.

```
var conn = new SqlConnection(masterData.DictRunData["ConnectionStringLocalDb"]);
const string objectName = "NotAvailable";
var dt = DateTime.Now;
var cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into CorporateDataStructure.dbo.ObjectInventory (location, object_name, object_id, object_xpath, time) values (@location, @object_name, @object_id, @object_xpath, @time)", conn);

foreach (var pair in webidsAndXPaths)
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@object_name", objectName));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@object_id", pair.Key));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@object_xpath", pair.Value));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@time", dt));

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
return true;
```

Comment: You can also use an `IDataReader`, e.g. from a `SELECT` statement that you have (using `sqlCmd.ExecuteReader()` you can get such an `IDataReader` for `SqlBulkCopy`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the appropriate columns to the `DataTable`, then loop all dictionary entries and add the rows:

```
var table = new System.Data.DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("object_name", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("object_id", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("object_xpath", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("time", typeof(DateTime));

foreach (var pair in webidsAndXPaths)
{
    table.Rows.Add(objectName, pair.Key, pair.Value, dt);
}
```

Instead of `table.Rows.Add` you could also use  this longer but readable approach using [`SetField`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336477%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
foreach (var pair in webidsAndXPaths)
{
    DataRow row = table.Rows.Add();
    row.SetField("object_name", objectName);
    row.SetField("object_id", pair.Key);
    row.SetField("object_xpath", pair.Value);
    row.SetField("time", dt);
}
```

Finally you need to use [`SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex21zs8x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn))
{
    conn.Open();
    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.ObjectInventory";
    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(table);
}
```

If the order of the columns in the `DataTable`  is the same as in the DB you don't  need to map columns.

Answer (score 2):

```
using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn, <SqlBulkCopyOptions>))
            {
                //dataTable definition
                var table = new System.Data.DataTable();
                table.Columns.Add("object_name", typeof(string));
                table.Columns.Add("object_id", typeof(int));
                table.Columns.Add("object_xpath", typeof(string));
                table.Columns.Add("time", typeof(DateTime));
                //bulkCopy options
                bulkCopy.BatchSize = webidsAndXPaths.Count();
                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "CorporateDataStructure.dbo.ObjectInventory";
                //bulkCopy mappings (not mandatory, just to avoid depending on column ordering in datatable)
                //That may avoid "strange" mistakes if you change something to your db or datatable.
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("object_name", "object_name");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("object_id", "object_id");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("object_xpath", "object_xpath");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("time", "time");

                //dataTable fedding from dictionary
                foreach (var pair in webidsAndXPaths)
                {
                     table.Rows.Add(objectName, pair.Key, pair.Value, dt);
                }
                //write to db.
                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(table);
            }
```